# How to align the content of pdf report when the data is entered continuously in editor for rendering the pdf

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, wicked-pdf

The content of the pdf report loses its alignment and body content gets shrinked when the data is entered continuously in the editor while rendering the pdf. The font-size of the content of generated pdf report also decreases.I am using the tinymce editor for inserting the data and wicked pdf gem to generate pdf.

In the image attached below i am entering the two lines continuously for point 1 in editor.Hence the alignment has lost in pdf report and the font-size of the pdf has decreased.  The css used for the pdf report is

```
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;

}

table
{
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    color:black; border-color:black;border-weight:1px;
    background : white;
    overflow: auto;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 100% !important;

}

table, tr, td
{
    border:0px solid #000000;
    font-size : 100%;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    width: auto;
}

hr {
    width: auto;
}
```

[image]
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the content continuously in editor it will take like a paragraph and in PDFs it will shrink the content